# Show different css span class with PHP

Tags: php, html, css

My **php script** call a value from a mysql table where row with name **CA_calorie** may have value 1 or 0.

Thats is how i call values from DB

```
<?php
    require_once 'connessione.php';
    $id=$_GET['id'];
    $query = "SELECT * FROM campi_name where id='$id' ";
    $stmt = $DBcon->prepare( $query );
    $stmt->execute();
    while($row=$stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
    ?>
```

When value is 1, HTML code should showing like that:

```
<tr>
  <td>
    <span>Calorie</span>
  </td>
  <td>
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></span>
  </td>
 </tr>
```

istead when value is 0, HTML code should showing like that:

```
<tr>
  <td>
    <span>Calorie</span>
  </td>
  <td>
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span>
  </td>
 </tr>
```

I don't know how do that in PHP or JS, someone can help me? Thank you!

Comment: the whole table row or just that td?

Comment: just class span

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply print dependent piece of `span`'s class based on `$row["CA_calorie"]`'s value:

```
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-<?php echo ($row["CA_calorie"]==1) ? 'ok' : 'remove'; ?>" ></span>
```